# Allow customer to change Quantity in cart

Tags: commerce

On my site it's not possible for customers to edit the quantity field in the cart view.

How do I allow that? I can't find a permission setting for this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the display settings of the product(#overlay=admin/structure/types/manage/product_display/display)
Click on the gear icon and select the checkbox "Display a textfield quantity widget on the add to cart form."[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want people to be able to quantity in the cart not on the product display

Comment: Instead of "Commerce line item : Quantity:,  add "Commerce Line Item: Quantity text field" in the shopping cart view.

Comment: that's already the field present in the view :-/

Comment: sorry, no it wasn't. that worked!